# Header set with query_string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am runing apache and I am trying to set a header Foo=bar only when the request has a variable "q" on the query string. I would like something like this in my htaccess:

```
<RequestUri "q=">
    Header set Foor "bar"
</RequestUri>
```

Of course it does not work. I already tried using "Location" and "LocationMatch" but those are not allowed inside the htaccess. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Apache 2.4, you can do something like this

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /q=.*?/">
    Header set Foo "bar"
</If>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: Thanks Sir. One final question: how do I check if a custom header exists? Like <If "%{CUSTOM_HEADER} =~ /.*/">  ?

Comment: is it possible to set the header Foo with the value of the query string? example "q=test" --> Foo: test

Comment: @user1361529 see my answer below for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on this further if you want to set the header's value dynamically according to the value of the query string you can capture regex groups.

For example if you have a "_locale" variable in your URL and you want to capture its value for a header you could use:

```
 <If %{QUERY_STRING} !~ m#_locale=([a-z]{2})#">
     RequestHeader set locale "$1"
</If>
```

*(Assuming the value will be two lower case letters.)*

This could match "_locale=en" in the query string then copy "en" to header "locale".